# How to change variable value in another php file

Tags: php

Basically, the file.php has variable name $email whose value I have to change. This is how far I have done it and it doesn't seem to work:

```
function updateFile($email) {

$file = 'file.php';
$content = file_get_contents($file, NULL);
$varname = '$email';
$newvalue = $email;
$content = preg_replace('/('. preg_quote($varname) .'=")[^"]+(")/', 
$varname."=\"".$newvalue."\"", $content);
file_put_contents($file, $content);

}

updateFile("test@gmail.com");
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to say. Can you apply your fix to my code? So I can see where you are suggesting the change.

Comment: So you want to replace `$email='some@valu.tld'` to `$email='test@gmail.com'`? If this is true, why do you need to do so?

Comment: My API requires it.

Comment: The fix provided by some guy whose comment vanished. I have tried the $$varname it seems to work but it changes values of other variable names in the file to the email.

Comment: In my experiance the biggest challenge with this kind of code is to get the regexpression right. Here is a useful online tool, which allows you to test your regexp easily and even generates the php code for it: https://regex101.com/
Once you are sure that your regexpression is correct and the code still doesn't work, than using a php debugger and going throught code line by line will help.

Comment: Seems nice way to debug but complicated for a noob like me.

Comment: You really, *REALLY* do not want to use self-modifying code - the security issue MikeT has mentioned is just the start of your problems.  **DO NOT DO THIS** see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752470/creating-a-config-file-in-php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the predicate for the question is invalid and the poster is asking how to implement a very dangrous solution.

Answer (score 2):

the best answer for this is even if you could, you shouldn't, it is a massive security risk to allow remote rewriting of your server files

as for why it is not safe lets say your file.php contains

$email = "defaultValue";

i then used your function to set the email to `"; file_put_contents("file.php", ""); $junk = "`

afterwards your file.php would read

```
$email = ""; file_put_contents("file.php", ""); $junk = "";
```

then when you ran file.php it would wipe itself

---

better ways to do the things you are describing are

parameters so in `file.php`you have a function that accepts $email as a parameter and uses that

file inclusion

if you have this code

```
$email = "blah@foo.bar";
include('file.php');
```

where "file.php' is

```
<?php echo $email;?>
```

will output `blah@foo.bar`

you could also combine this with a config file

ie

```
include('config.php');
echo $email;
```

where "config.php' is

```
<?php $email = "blah@foo.bar";?>
```

Session if you set a session variable of Email then you can use that from any file that is on the same session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();        
}
$email = "defaultValue"
if (array_key_exists("email", $_SESSION)) 
    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
```

**EDIT**: to clarify the examples above as you are having trouble conceptualising

send an email via a parameter

lets say you have a PHP file as so

```
function SendEmail(array $email)
{
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();
    $transport->setLocalDomain();


    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

    $message->setTo($email);
    $message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
    $message->setBody("Test");
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    return $mailer->send($message);
}
```

or using an externally defined variable

```
$email = "blah@foo.bar";
include('file.php');
```

where file.php is

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();
$transport->setLocalDomain();


// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

$message->setTo($email);
$message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
$message->setBody("Test");
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
return $mailer->send($message);

$email = "blah@foo.bar";
include('file.php');
```

or using a session

```
function updateEmail($email) {

    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_start();        
    }
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
}
```

updateEmail("test@gmail.com");

where file.php is

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();        
}
$email = "defaultValue"
if (array_key_exists("email", $_SESSION)) 
    $email = $_SESSION["email"];

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();
$transport->setLocalDomain();


// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

$message->setTo($email);
$message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
$message->setBody("Test");
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
return $mailer->send($message);
```

all of the above are safe ways to change a variable in a external code file with out opening your system to hacking

Comment: I don't want to print the $email nor want to use it. Just want to replace the email value in the file without affecting other variables in the file.

Comment: printing is just  an example of how you can affect the value of a variable in a file with out altering the file

Comment: I don't want to do the above way. Can you suggest preg_replace way? I am able to manipulate the email value if I define the exact email value but I don't want that what I want is to change the variable value without knowing the value of it.

Comment: as i said editing your source PHP files directly is a security risk, your API can not require that functionality, what your API requires is to change the value of the $email variable, of which writing the file is the wrong way to do it and i've provided several ways.