# Is it possible to get returned data from a file in PHP?

Tags: php

I am creating a reusable app, which requires some configurations stored in `config.php`. This configuration file does not have any function, but the configuration are returned as an array, eg

```
<?php

return [
    'db_name' => 'db_name',
    'password' => 'password',
     ........
];
```

I was hoping to create a function which includes this config file, and get each config set. An example is laravel `config()` function which returns a configuration value. Is there any way to acheive this?

I have tried

```
$filename = 'config.php';
include $filename;
$contents[] = file_get_contents($filename);
```

but this just gets whatever is in the file as a string.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Hint: please try searching before posting a new question.  I tried super vague terms like "*php get common config*" and found many answers here already.

Comment: You do not want `file_get_contents()`. That will get the contents of a file. The methods described in the answers given here and the approach that uses `return` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752470/creating-a-config-file-in-php bring the code in *config.php* into your script as if it was actually code written in your script.

Comment: You was so near, just needed `$config = include('config.php');`

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, this is possible if you assign the config array to a variable instead of `return`:

```php
<?php

$config = [
    'db_name' => 'db_name',
    'password' => 'password',
     ........
];
```

Then, you can access the `$config` everywhere this file is included. You don't need `file_get_contents` in this case.

But please note that this solution adds a potential vulnerability to your application, literally allowing to execute an arbitrary code provided inside `config.php`.
Instead of storing the configuration in a php file, consider using the [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) component, or if this too complex for your app, use a harmless format such as JSON or YAML:

config.json:

```json
{
    "db_name": "some_name",
    "password": "some_password",
    ...
}
```

then, in your code:

```
$filename = 'config.json';
$parsed = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);
echo $parsed['db_name'];  // -> some_name
echo $parsed['password']; // -> some_password
```

Comment: If you write the code inside *config.php* yourself, it will be as safe or dangerous as any other code you write in your application. If you are importing it from somewhere else then I guess JSON or YAML are safer formats as there is a limit to what they can cause your program to do.

Comment: @user3425506 thanks for your note. I said _potential_ vulnerability meaning some day that config is supposed to be imported from some external source.

Comment: Using `return` is welcome to do this: `$config = include('config.php');`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I have just followed the link from where your question was closed ([Creating a config file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752470/creating-a-config-file-in-php)) and was interested to find out that the approach you have taken (using `return`) does appear to be valid and is recommended there. So, don't let me put you off that. I always do it like I explain below:

In *config.php* get rid of `return` and assign the array to a variable.

```
<?php
$config =  [
    'db_name' => 'db_name',
    'password' => 'password',
     ........
];
```

Then use `require_once './config.php';` to get it into any *.php* script you like. You can then use *$config* in that script.

Note the path to *config.php* must be correct. I have assumed above that it is in the same directory as the file you are importing it into with `require_once` so the path used was `./config.php`. If *config.php* was in the parent directory of the file using it then the path would have had two dots: `../config.php`.